# Look behind replace all occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, regex-group

I want to replace all occurences of .digit with 0.digit.

I'm new to regular expressions but as far as I understand I could use look behind to do this. But JS does not support that, I'd like to know if someone knows a solution. 
To show the problem I wrote the following code.

```
str = "0.11blabla.22bla0.33bla.33"
allow = "\\.\\d*"
str.match(new RegExp(allow,"g"))
[".11", ".22", ".33", ".33"]
deny = "0\\.\\d*"
str.match(new RegExp(deny,"g"))
["0.11", "0.33"]
diffreg= new RegExp("(?!"+deny+")"+allow,"g") // translates to: /(?!0\.\d*)\.\d*/g
str.match(diffreg)
[".11", ".22", ".33", ".33"]
```

Obviously allow matches all decimal values whereas deny matches all values with a preceding 0. The result should of course be the set difference between the two: [".33", ".33"].

Comment: What is the expected output that you want from `intersectionreg` ?

Comment: Why not use a grouping match `str.match(/([^0])(\.\d)/g);`?

Comment: Are you sure you mean "intersection"? I suspect you want set-difference: all of those in set "allow" that are not in set "deny" (intersection is those that are in both sets).

Comment: Thanks guys, this works! Richard you are correct of course. I edited the question using the term "difference" instead of "intersecting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this regex instead

```
  [0]?(\.\d*)
```

So in your code you will have:

```
intersectionreg = new RegExp("[0]?("+allow+")","g")
```

Thanks @richard, **edited**

Comment: Unfortunately that would not match ".1" at the beginning of the string.

Comment: This did the trick, but I had another error, because I did not know that "*" also matches 0 occurences i needed to use "+". The final regex is:
str.replace(/[0]?(\.\d+)/g,"0$1")

Answer (score 1):

Use a [group match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```
> str.replace(/([^0])(\.\d)/g, "$10$2");
"0.11blabla0.22bla0.33bla0.33"
```